# TypeError: compile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

What is the 'self' in the model.compile? I try to run code with python in keras model I get this error:

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
TypeError: compile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 4):

instantiate the Class and then use methods...
it should be something like this

```
model().compile()

or 
m = model()
m.compile()
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need to show more code to get an appropriate answer, but i give it a try:

If you want to compile the model you need to do at least following steps:

1. `from keras.models import Model`
2. `model = Model(inputs=in, outputs=out)` - where `in` is the input layer and `out` is the output layer.
3. `model.compile(loss=someLoss, optimizer=someOpt)`

Answer (score 1):

There are parameters to compile the model like:

If you have defined a [Sequential](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) model then you can directly call [compile](https://keras.io/models/sequential/).

```
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=..., metrics=...)
```

Otherwise, you need to build a model using [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) and use the above code to compile the model.

```
# input is the input layer and output is the output layer.
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```